# Helix 3D Toolkit: Not accessible in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, helix-3d-toolkit

I want to use Helix 3d Toolkit in my WPF application with C#. From [site](https://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/76036) today I downloaded HelixToolkit-2014.1.2.1.zip and extracted in a folder. It contains folders for NET 4.0 & 4.5 respectively.

In my application, I added reference for HelixToolkit.Wpf.dll and tried to access in xaml. Using an [example as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793037/drawing-a-3d-pipe-using-wpf) I started creating xaml.

```
<Window x:Class="Learn3DApp.HelixExamples"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:helix="clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf"
    Title="HelixExamples" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <helix:HelixViewport3D x:Name="mainViewPort" >

    </helix:HelixViewport3D>
</Grid>
```

On `<helix:HelixViewport3D` line I get error "The name HellxViewport3D does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf". The clr line is not underlined, but  is underlined and the error also appears in that line only.

In code behind I tried and could add `using HelixToolkit.Wpf;` and also access HelicViewport3d easily without any problem.

My project is of Target Net 4.5, I tried adding HelixToolkit of 4.0 and 4.5 also (1 after another). But same problem in both the dlls'. Why so ?? I am using VS 2012.

What seems to be the problem ? Am I missing anything OR clr is not proper ??? OR is this Helix version not proper - which one to use ?? 
I am stuck and not able to move ahead. Have spent almost half day figuring the problem. If anyone can help me out, it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using visual studio something you might want to try is add the helixtoolkit to your toolbox and drag the control onto the screen and see what value it generates for you. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165355%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Also, I have noticed with WPF and silverlight, that you can get this error message a lot but the thing still runs and compiles, might not be the same in your current case.

Comment: I've just tested the 4.5 version in VS2013 and works ok. Noticed the namespace was different though xmlns:helix="http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com"

Comment: I tried both the ways, but no success. I even used dll & clr line from Examples\SimpleDemo, thinking that the example dll will be definitely working. But NO, now I get "Assembly 'HelixToolkit.Wpf' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference. Also verify that your project and all referenced assemblies have been built." I checked the properties of dll, the assembly name is correct. The dll is used by examples and the SimpleDemo executes nicely.

Comment: On accessing from Toolbox, I get msg it has been added to the project, ...Press OK & xaml desiner will restart, re-create the control on the artboard". What is artboard ? What ^ how do I have to re-create ?? I can't get this msg. Is it that Helix doesn't support VS 2012 due to any reasons !! DO I have to add any other dll's along with HelixToolkit.Wpf ???

Comment: From toolbox, I added in XAML, now I get msg - "HelixViewport3D is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Project". I had thought Helix is an extension of WPF 3D and it supports WPF. But what is this ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build the source code of Helix and created dll, and that worked for me.

This this helps others too.

Comment: This helped me as well.

Answer (score 0):

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70443425/10609393). Specifically, take a look on how he referenced the helix namespace.