# how to use a xaml file in WPF that does not have an .cs

Tags: helix-3d-toolkit

I have a .xaml file from, HelixToolkit how do I use it in Microsoft Visual Studio?
Is don't have a .cs.
has anyone used this before?

Answer (score 2):

It is totally possible to create some scenes in a viewport directly in XAML without necessarily editing the codebehind of a WPF application.

[Here](http://docs.helix-toolkit.org/en/latest/wpf/getting-started.html) you will have an example:

1. Create a new Project in Visual Studio in WPF C#
2. Add the “HelixToolkit.Wpf” NuGet package
3. Add a new key to reference the toolkit

```xml
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:hx="clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf" <<< Here!
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

4. Add HelixViewPort3D inside the grid
5. Add Light
6. Add objects to the scene

```xml
<Grid>
    <hx:HelixViewport3D ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True">
        <!-- Remember to add light to the scene -->
        <hx:SunLight/>
        <!-- Teapot is a test object -->
        <hx:Teapot/>
        <!-- Add a Cube -->
        <hx:CubeVisual3D Center="5,0,0" SideLength="2" Fill="Orange"/>
    </hx:HelixViewport3D>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).